# Laravel store request all better way

Tags: laravel

I have following code:

```
    //Create Assignment
    $customer['projects_id'] = $Project->id;
    $customer['user_id'] = $customeruser['user_id'];
    $customer['user_name'] = $SalesRepresentative->user_name;
    $customer['user_role'] = "Admin";
    ProjectUser::firstOrCreate($customer);
```

Is there a way to write this code cleaner and don't have 4 lines? Maybe one instead? Thanks. request has a lot more values.

Comment: show your full code

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a validating request class you can simply call     `ProjectUser::firstOrCreate($request->validated());` in that case, only validated variables are passed to store method.